# Update query using select data

Tags: php, mysql

take a look at my table first please:

[user_id, row_id, row_value] - table: users_data

Content:

## row_id 1:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 2]
[4, 1, 2]
```

## row_id 2:

```
[1, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[4, 2, 1]
```

## row_id 3:

```
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 5]
```

I would like to find out if it is possible to do those 3 steps only by using MySQL language automatically:

Step 1: Get list of `row_id` of user_id = 1(so [1, 1, 1] and [1, 2, 1])

Step 2: Iterate through that list to find out what are most popular row_values JUST for row_ids that are in the list gained from Step 1

Step 3: Iterate through result of Step 2 to make row_values of user_id = 1, be just the same as most popular row_values.

Now thats the queries i have made:

Step 1:

`SELECT row_id FROM users_data WHERE user_id = 1;`

Result of that query are 2 rows:

- [1]
- [2]

Step 2: So now from those 2 rows, somehow 2 queries should be run(filled with data of Step 1):

`SELECT row_id, row_value FROM users_data WHERE row_id = 1 GROUP BY row_value  ORDER BY COUNT(row_value) LIMIT 1;`

`SELECT row_id, row_value FROM users_data WHERE row_id = 2 GROUP BY row_value  ORDER BY COUNT(row_value) LIMIT 1;`

Result of 1st query:

[1, 2]

Result of 2nd query:

[2, 1]

Step 3: And finally from those 2 rows, i would like to update user 1 row_values. So something like this should be run:

`UPDATE users_data SET row_value = 2 WHERE user_id = 1 AND row_id = 1;`

`UPDATE users_data SET row_value = 1 WHERE user_id = 1 AND row_id = 2;`

So i would like those steps to be done automatically(data for step 3 taken from step 2, data from step 2 taken from step 1) but i do not know how to make it(now i can just write it in programming language or fill queries with notepad).

Here are the queries in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d5594/14

Comment: how did you get 3 in `[1, 2, 3]` (on step 2)?

Comment: it is hard to understand what you want, can you refrase question plz?

Comment: do you accept mysql vars for temporary result storing?

Comment: Please make your question more clear.

Comment: Here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d5594/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing, but this seems to do that:

```sql
UPDATE users_data u_old
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT u1.user_id, u2.row_id, u2.row_value
    FROM users_data u1
    JOIN users_data u2 USING(row_id)
    WHERE u1.user_id = 1
        AND u2.row_value = (
            SELECT u3.row_value 
            FROM users_data u3
            WHERE u3.row_id = u2.row_id
            GROUP BY u3.row_value
            ORDER BY COUNT(u3.row_value) DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
) u_new USING (user_id, row_id)
SET u_old.row_value = u_new.row_value
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/116ab0/3

Comment: Exactly, that's what i wanted :) Thank you very much

Comment: I changed the solution a little bit without changing the result. Because of `WHERE u3.row_id = u2.row_id` in the innermost subselect, `row_id` is not needed in the GROUP BY list, neither in the SELECT list. It is "constant" for that subselect. For same reason i removed it from the WHERE condition of the outer subselect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your question, you want to find the most "popular" row value(s) and then set all the rows returned from `Step 2` to be them? But what do you mean by most "popular"(s)? If you mean find the single most popular `row_value`, then it seems that you want to be able to do something like this (and hopefully this should give you some ideas if it is not what you mean):

#### Step 1: Get result rows where `user_id` = 1

```
SELECT row_id FROM users_data WHERE user_id = 1;
```

#### Step 2: Figure out the most popular `row_id`

```
 SELECT a.row_value 
 FROM (
     SELECT COUNT(*), row_value
     FROM users_data 
     WHERE user_id = 1
     GROUP BY row_value
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
     LIMIT 1
 ) as a
```

#### Now update them:

```
 UPDATE `users_data` SET row_values =  
 (
     SELECT a.row_value 
     FROM (
         SELECT COUNT(*), row_value
         FROM users_data 
         WHERE user_id = 1
         GROUP BY row_value
         ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
         LIMIT 1
     ) 
 as a) 
 WHERE user_id = 1;
```